# Wifi won't automatically connect if ethernet connected

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I recently bought a Belkin AC876 USB wifi adapter for my desktop, but I've noticed that it will not automatically connect if I also have an ethernet cable connected as well. As soon as I disable the ethernet adapter, the wifi connects immediately. I can also manually connect the wifi and have both run without an issue. What gives?

If you're wondering why I want both, I'm using the ethernet to directly connect to my Synology NAS but using the wifi for internet access.

Comment: What operating system are you using? This is pretty important, since the OS is, after all, responsible for things like automatic WiFi configuration on modern systems.

Comment: Derp, right. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 8 doesn't automatically join Wi-Fi network if Ethernet connection is active; router prevents Ethernet devices from seeing some Wi-Fi devices](https://superuser.com/questions/504261/windows-8-doesnt-automatically-join-wi-fi-network-if-ethernet-connection-is-act)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but I'll post this in case someone else comes along. Apparently this is standard Windows functionality as of 8. There's a registry setting you can change to get both connections working. https://superuser.com/a/630163/508037

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Network and Sharing Centre** in **Control Panel** and **Change adapter Settings**. Press **ALT**, up top of the window press **Advanced** and click **Advanced Settings**, on the window you'll be able to move your wireless connection to the top(higher priority) and once saved if the wifi is detected it should connect to this once first before hopping to Ethernet.

Comment: I've tried this to no effect. I also went in and manually set the metric on each interface such that wireless was lower than ethernet and while that does make traffic flow through the wifi when both are connected, Windows still won't automatically connect the wifi if the ethernet is plugged in.

Comment: Wow that is strange, might be a bug in Windows 10. I have a WiFi adapter I might try it out see if happens for me.

Comment: I even went so far as to bumb my ethernet adapter down to 100mbps so it would be slower than my wifi and still nothing.

Comment: I found a crappy workaround by creating a scheduled task that triggers on log on and the Powe-Troubleshooter event. It calls:
`netsh wlan connect name=mySsid`

Comment: Apparently this is normal behavior as of windows 8. I've tested it on 3 other machines and they all do the same thing. The good news is that I may have a regedit solution that I'll try this evening.

Answer (score -1):

This works on Win 10 and probably win 8.

Open up Task Scheduler

Create Task..., give it a name like "wifi"

Triggers: new: begin the task: "at log on"

Actions: New: under "Program/script" type: netsh, under add arguments type:

*wlan connect name=MYSSID* (and replace MYSSID with your network name)

Comment: This doesn't overwrite the default OS behavior.